# compare percentage values with xsl:choose

Tags: html, xml, xslt, compare

In XSL version 1.0 sheet I am populating a html table with percentage values from an xml. I would like to display the highlighted color of the percantages based on condition but the condition isn't processed as desired, therefore ignoring the condition in some way.

Relevant XSL:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number(substring-before('diskspace','%')) &gt; 80"><td bgcolor="red"><xsl:value-of select="diskspace"/></td></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><td bgcolor="green"><xsl:value-of select="diskspace"/></td></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

 <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="number(substring-before('freeSwap','k')) &lt; .1*number(substring-before('totalSwap','k'))"><td bgcolor="red"><xsl:value-of select="freeSwap"/></td></xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise><td bgcolor="green"><xsl:value-of select="cpuUsage"/></td></xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

Is there something wrong with my test conditions? It is meant to convert the percentage value to a number to compare to another number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the quotes off of `diskspace` and `freeSwap` if they're intended to reference element values.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion from kjhughes led to fixing issue: "Take the quotes off of diskspace and freeSwap if they're intended to reference element values"